# Sources for learning Lie groups and symplectic geometry for Quantum optics

Tags: reference-request, physics, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry

I am asking this question on behalf of my junior who has recently joined in the graduate programme. As suggested by my boss, the student wants to work on quantum optics from a symplectic geometric point of view. Now being a maths student, it came to me to suggest suitable mathematics books to prepare himself and polish his maths.  He is done masters in physics and has reasonably strong knowledge in quantum mechanics (Sakurai I was their text book). I have suggested [Symplectic Geometry and Quantum Mechanics by Maurice A. Gosson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764375744), Brian Hall's [Lie groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441923136), and [Quantum mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146147115X) for reading. My question what books can be suitable for students with physics background to understand topic like Symplectic geometry and  Lie group representation? Advanced thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Foundations of Mechanics by Jerry Marsden is a great book on differential geometry, symplectic geometry, and lie groups done from the point of view of Hamiltonian and Lagrangian mechanics. No quantum, but it might help with the understanding of the mathematics

Comment: @mtiano thanks a lot. my friend needs to learn maths (easily) for his future works. however i still want to know about something which connects with quantum optics. he had some previous difficulties with Arnold's book.